# Google analytics on wp

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

Am i right, assuming i cant load this analytics scripts from external .js file?

```
    (function(b, o, i, l, e, r) {
        b.GoogleAnalyticsObject = l;
        b[l] || (b[l] =
            function() {
                (b[l].q = b[l].q || []).push(arguments)
            });
        b[l].l = +new Date;
        e = o.createElement(i);
        r = o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
        e.src = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
        r.parentNode.insertBefore(e, r)
    }(window, document, 'script', 'ga'));
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

But can i put it into footer.php? which is a include on site, or do i have to keep it on every page as an inline script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But can i put it into footer.php which is a include on site, or do i
>   have to keep it on every page as an inline script?

If you put this in a php footer file it will become an inline Javascript in every page that includes the footer, so technically the answer is "both".

However if you include this in an include/inline code you need to wrap it in "`<script></script>`" tags. Also you might lose a few pageviews, since a user might be able to leave the page before the code is executed (depending on how long it takes to load the page).

Comment: Thanks thats, pretty accurate answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have the GA script in a separate .js file and enqueue that on those sites where you like to show it.

The script can be inserted in either the header, or the footer (end of your page), but google recommends putting it inside your  tags to start the loading of it early on.